# why output of yaml.safe_load('1:1') returns a number not an error?

Tags: python-3.x, pyyaml

I missed a space after `:`, but found an interesting result. I couldn't get why the output is 6241.

```py
>>> import yaml
>>> 
>>> yaml.safe_load('104:1')
6241
```

Comment: `104:1` denotes a timestamp. 104 * 60 + 1 == 6241.

Comment: Thanks! `:`  denotes a timestamp in regexp!